# Erase old iPhone - forgotten restrictions passcode and no WiFi

Tags: ios, iphone

I have an old iPhone 4 that has been sitting unused since I got my new phone - it has now sold and I have to clean it out so it's ready for the next person.

Here's the problem:

1. The wifi doesn't work and the phone's inactivated (so I can't get online).
2. It is asking for a restrictions passcode I don't ever remember setting.

I tried the default (0000) but no luck. What can I do to get this phone back to factory settings?

Comment: FWIW, there is no default passcode. You set up the passcode when you enable restrictions and there is no standard passcode as you are required to enter one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To bypass a forgotten Restrictions password, you must restore the phone as a 'new phone' by connecting to iTunes, without restoring any backup.

You must also make sure to remove the phone from iCloud before you sell it -
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201351
otherwise the next owner will not be able to activate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can wipe your iPhone with iTunes: [Apple's support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201252)

Sometimes, it's also possible to recover the restrictions passcode, but that requires a lot of work. [2](http://www.igeeksblog.com/how-to-reset-restriction-passcode-on-iphone-ipad-using-ibackupbot/)

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the restrictions passcode for iPhone 4 (iOS 6-specific) by following the steps outline in the blogpost found [here](http://www.simonblog.com/2011/03/16/how-to-recover-forgotten-iphone-restrictions-passcode/).

Also, for iOS 7 and iOS 8, I've published an updated version of the blogpost cited above.  My new one can be found at http://excentrix.io/recover-your-ios-78-restrictions-passcode-forgotten-or-otherwise/.